# Highcharts csv export issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highchart in my application .I am unable to export the chart datapoints to csv format .

I tried using this approach

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script  src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/export-csv/master/export-csv.js"></script>

$('#getcsv').click(function () {
    var charts1 = $('#aumChart-container').highcharts();
    Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
        csv: charts1.getCSV()
    });
});
```

By using this approach i see the default the highcharts context menu inside my chart control .I want to have a csv export from an external button .Is there a way to remove this default context menu .

I tried removing the context menu by removing the reference to exporting.js but then my export to csv from external BUTTON stops working .

Can someone let me know where exactly i am messing up?

Comment: it first checks if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting) {  before adding the button, so you should be able to change that option somehow  to keep it from appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

There's a [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export-CSV) that allows you to export CSV (which is what you're using).

On that same page they've shown how you can use an alert box to get the CSV, would that be sufficient?

Direct link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/)

**Option 2**

You can code it so that only specific menu items are [available](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons)

The above link - you're looking for "menuItems"

But instead - you would have:

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: [{
                    text: 'CSV',
                    onclick: function() {
                        /* 
                            obviously you'd have to post this to a script
                            to get the results into a csv file
                            instead of getting an alert. 
                        */
                        alert(this.getCSV());   
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried approach : 1 but i need to download the csv file too rather than just the alert .with approach 2 could you tell me how can post it to the script to get the results in csv file.i was using this php file to download csv file:Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-              export/csv.php', {
            csv: charts1.getCSV()
        });                                                                              .This script doesnt works for me ,is  there a better way to do it

Comment: 1) You need to check how to prepare file in javascript, it is not related with highcharts.